# Make std vector of Eigen vectors from Eigen Matrix

Tags: c++, std, eigen

I have an a `Eigen::MatrixXd` that I made from `std::vector` of `Eigen::Vector3d`. It was easy.

I made some transform manipulation on that matrix and I want return result as std vector of `Eigen::Vector3d`.

How could I make

`std::vector<Eigen::Vector3d>` form `Eigen::Matrix3d?`

Comment: Using a std::vector<Eigen::Vector3d> does not sound like a good idea. Why not just a MatixXd ?

Answer (score 3):

Better stick with the `std::vector` object. Here is how I usually deal with such cases:

```
std::vector<Vector3d> vecs(n);
auto mat = Matrix3Xd::Map(vecs[0].data(), 3, vecs.size());
```

This creates a view on the data owned by `vecs`. Then play with `mat` as you like (except resizing of course!), eg.:

```
mat = my_affine * mat;
```

No need to copy back the values from `mat` to `vecs`, but of course, if you have a `Matrix3Xf` or `MatrixXf`  already at hand and want to copy it to `vecs`, then simply write:

```
mat = other_mat;
```

Provided that `vecs.size() == other_mat.cols()`, otherwise you need to resize `vecs` first and re-create a `Map` with new size.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @ggael and @RHertel that you should stick with one representation. If you need to dynamically insert `Vector3d` objects, then `std::vector` is probably the better solution (and you can still access it like an Eigen object, using `Eigen::Map` as shown by ggael).

Likewise, if you have a `Matrix3Xd` and want to use it column-wise in a standard algorithm, you can do that using `.colwise().begin()` and `.colwise().end()` which by itself won't copy any data (this requires the development branch of Eigen -- or the upcoming 3.4 version).

This also gives an easy way to create an `std::vector` from an `Eigen::Matrix3Xd`:

```
// `mat` needs to have 3 rows (at runtime)
std::vector<Eigen::Vector3d> vec(mat.colwise().begin(), mat.colwise().end());
```

Godbolt-Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/uCqZni