# Convert std::vector<double> to std::vector<Eigen:Vector3d>

Tags: c++, eigen, hdf5, open3d

I'd like to know how to convert a `std::vector<double>` into a `std::vector<Eigen:Vector3d>`. The context is that I am reading point cloud data (x,y,z points) from an HDF5 file, which has been flattened into 1d array, into a `std::vector<double>`, so the `std::vector<double>` always has nx3 number of points.

I am using libeigen3-dev (3.3.7).

Previously, I was reading the data out from the h5 file into a `std::vector<double>` and then using `Eigen::Map` to convert to a `Eigen::VectorXd` as so:

```
Eigen::VectorXd readH5Data(H5::DataSet &dataset, H5::VarLenType memType, H5::DataSpace &dataspace, H5::DataSpace &memspace, int index) {

    // Initialize hyperslabs
    hsize_t dataCount[1];
    hsize_t dataOffset[1];
    hsize_t memCount[1];
    hsize_t memOffset[1];

    // Select hyperslabs
    dataCount[0] = 1;
    dataOffset[0] = index;
    memCount[0] = 1;
    memOffset[0] = 0;
    dataspace.selectHyperslab(H5S_SELECT_SET, dataCount, dataOffset);
    memspace.selectHyperslab(H5S_SELECT_SET, memCount, memOffset);

    // Read out the data as std::vector<double>
    std::vector<hvl_t> varlenSpecs(1);
    dataset.read(varlenSpecs.data(), memType, memspace, dataspace);
    auto dataPtr = static_cast<double*>(varlenSpecs[0].p);
    std::vector<double> readOut(dataPtr, dataPtr + varlenSpecs[0].len);
    H5free_memory(varlenSpecs[0].p);
    
    // Convert std::vector<double> to Eigen::VectorXd
    double* ptr = &readOut[0];
    Eigen::Map<Eigen::VectorXd> dataOut(ptr, readOut.size());    

    return dataOut;
}
```

I could then convert the 1d `Eigen::VectorXd` to an nx3 `Eigen::MatrixXd`, as follows, and do whatever additional processing:

```
Eigen::VectorXd points = readH5Data(datasetPts, memTypeDbl, dataspacePts, memspacePts, 0);

Eigen::MatrixXd ptsMat = Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixXd>(points.data(), 3, nPoints).transpose();
```

However, I now need to construct an [Open3D PointCloud](http://www.open3d.org/docs/latest/cpp_api/classopen3d_1_1geometry_1_1_point_cloud.html) using these data points, which is constructed as follows:

```
PointCloud (const std::vector< Eigen::Vector3d > &points)
```

So I require the data to be set up as `std::vector<Eigen::Vector3d>`. So, I'd ideally like to modify my readH5Data function to return `std::vector<Eigen::Vector3d>`. I believe I can do the conversion from an `Eigen::MatrixXd` [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58319313/make-std-vector-of-eigen-vectors-from-eigen-matrix):

```
std::vector<Eigen::Vector3d> vec(ptsMat.colwise().begin(), ptsMat.colwise().end());
```

but I'm wondering if I can avoid that intermediate step and go directly from `std::vector<double>` to `std::vector<Eigen::Vector3d>`.

Comment: I cannot come up with something nice and clean with my first ideas. But you maybe can experiment with a for-loop over the iterator; something similar to this:
```
for( auto iter=doubvec.cbegin(); iter!=doubvec.cend(); std::advance(iter,3) )
   eigvec.emplace_back(*iter,*(iter+1),*(iter+2));
```
This is untested, just typed here, not checked for spelling errors. Also you might want to make sure before this for-llop that doubvec.size is divisable by 3 without remainder.
A solution that uses std algorithms would be much cleaner, but I can't figure out how to formulate that right now.

Comment: Consider: Don't read it into a vector of doubles? I do not see the utility of that step.  In fact, possibly don't even copy the floats out of the H5 buffer (which probably involves not using vector as your base container; a unique_ptr<T[], custom_deleter>`.  This depends on how important not copying this buffer is: the more work you put in, the fewer copies you can do.

Comment: You're making this way too complicated. What's up with that `varlenSpecs`? What shape and datatype does the dataset have?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I wondered whether to add the HDF5 stuff b/c ultimately I  want to know how to go from std::vector<double> -> std:vector<Eigen:Vector3d>, but thought it might help understand the context. The point cloud data I work with is in an h5 file. The reason for varlenSpecs is b/c the h5 contains 1000s of point clouds, each with different numbers of points. They are stored as variable-length 1d arrays inside the h5 file, and currently come out as std::vector<double>, then Eigen::VectorXd. If someone knows how to extract directly into std::vector<Eigen::Vector3d>, even better.

Comment: What I need is to construct the Open3D PointCloud from std::vector<Eigen::Vector3d>, where each Vector3d is one xyz point in the point cloud. Currently, I can extract my n xyz data points from the h5 into std::vector<double> of size 3n, convert it to Eigen::VectorXd of size 3n, convert to n x 3 Eigen::MatrixXd, then finally an n-length std::vector<Eigen::Vector3d>. I'd like to go std::vector<double> direct to std::vector<Eigen::Vector3d> if possible. I didn't ask about h5 directly to vector<Vector3d> bc my exp. is that it's very hard to get help with HDF5, esp. pertaining to var-length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, let's break this down a bit, mostly for my understanding of your code. Please double-check this. It also means my solution is only valid as long as these conditions hold.

```cpp
auto dataPtr = static_cast<double*>(varlenSpecs[0].p);
std::vector<double> readOut(dataPtr, dataPtr + varlenSpecs[0].len);
```

This tells me whatever your memory datatype is, it's no `struct`-like type or anything fancy, just a basic array of doubles. This simplifies things a lot.

```cpp
Eigen::MatrixXd ptsMat =
    Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixXd>(points.data(), 3, nPoints).transpose();
```

So 3 rows, N columns in column-major order which means that `std::vector<Eigen::Vector3d>` will have the same layout in memory. There are two important aspects to note here for this:

1. The memory layout of `std::vector` is not opaque. It has to be implemented as a dynamic array and you are free to treat it as such
2. `Eigen::Vector3d` has no padding

This means that you can simply use `memcpy`. It's not fancy but it gets the job done with minimal overhead. One might object to the lack of memory safety but frankly, most of HDF5's API lacks memory safety and `Eigen::Map` doesn't, either.

```cpp
static_assert(sizeof(Eigen::Vector3d) == 3 * sizeof(double));
std::vector<Eigen::Vector3d> rtrn(varlenSpecs.len / 3);
std::memcpy(rtrn.data(), varlenSpecs.p, varlenSpecs.len * sizeof(double));
```

The whole reading function can be cleaned up, too.

```cpp
std::vector<Eigen::Vector3d> readH5Data(
        H5::DataSet &dataset, const H5::VarLenType& memType, int index)
{
    hsize_t dataCount = 1;
    hsize_t dataOffset = index;
    H5::DataSpace dataspace = dataset.getSpace();
    dataspace.selectHyperslab(H5S_SELECT_SET, &dataCount, &dataOffset);
    H5::DataSpace mspace(1, &dataCount);
    std::vector<Eigen::Vector3d> rtrn;
    hvl_t varlenSpecs;
    dataset.read(&varlenSpecs, memType, mspace, dataspace);
    try {
        rtrn.resize(varlenSpecs.len / 3);
    } catch(std::bad_alloc&) {
        H5free_memory(varlenSpecs.p);
        throw;
    }
    static_assert(sizeof(Eigen::Vector3d) == 3 * sizeof(double));
    std::memcpy(rtrn.data(), varlenSpecs.p, varlenSpecs.len * sizeof(double));
    H5free_memory(varlenSpecs.p);
    return rtrn;
}
```

Note how there is no point in using 1-sized arrays. Just use scalars. I also don't see a reason to pass in the `DataSpace` objects. If anything, it makes it more error-prone.

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked perfectly. I'll just say I had to fix a couple typos to compile it: datacount -> dataCount, memspace -> mspace, but I'm only pointing it out in case someone else ever comes across this; not a big deal at all. Thanks also for cleaning up the function, much appreciated. As I'm sure you can tell, I'm not a heavy C++ user, so I can learn from this type of thing. Also confirmed I can construct the Open3D PointCloud from the rtrn.